# the type getIntent() is undefined for adapter

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting a byteArray from another activity via Intent like this:

```
        if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(mContext);
    }
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
      Bitmap default_b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
      view.setImageBitmap(default_b);
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
```

But I get the error that getIntent() is undefined for the type GridViewAdapter (this is in my base adapter class for a gridView)

I create the intent here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridViewAdapter.class);
                                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

How can I fix this error?

ADDED:

Here is my full part where I create the intent:

```
        Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Data Set To Display");
    addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                            .getApplicationIcon(entry.activityInfo.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon
                                scaleDownBitmap(default_b, 100, v.getContext());
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");

                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap to Array");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridViewAdapter.class);
                                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Intent started to send Bitmap");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIntent()` is used to get the `Intent` used to start an `Activity`. Since you aren't in an `Activity` then there is no `Intent` to "get" and `getIntent()`, as it says, is not a function of the `Adapter` class.

Use that code in the `Activity` that calls the `Adapter` class and pass the data needed to that class

Comment: I get the error that getIntent() is undefined for the type Context

Comment: Yeah, see my updated answer, I was a bit confused as to what you had

Answer (score 3):

Pass your Activity context to the Adapter constructor

there you can access your intent like this

```
((Activity)mContext).getIntent()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
 Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
 int value = intent.getIntExtra("myvalue", 0);
```